# PGFPlots: semilogxaxis and y axis tick marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to set up a `semilogxaxis` in `pgfplots`.  The image I am trying to generate is
[image]
but my code below is generating
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogxaxis}[
    ylabel = Gain db,
    xlabel = Frequency Hz,
    ytick = {0, 100},
    xtickten = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
  \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess what you're asking is: Why does the x range only run from 10^0 to 10^0.4? Is that correct?

Comment: @Jake yes and similar on y when I set it other wise.

Comment: If you check your `.log` file, you'll see `Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.`. Setting `ytick` and `ytickten` doesn't influence the axis limits, it just specifies where to put tick labels. To set the axis limits, use `xmin` and `xmax` (or just add the `\addplot` command that plots your data, then the axis limits will be set to accommodate the data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it this, what you are looking for?

**Disclaimer:** I'm a newbie with `pgfplots`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogxaxis}[
            axis x line=center,
            axis y line=left,
            xmajorgrids=true,
            xlabel style={below=3ex},
            enlarge x limits,
            ymax = 150,
            ytick = {100},
            ylabel = Gain db,
            xlabel = Frequency Hz,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {(1e2,100) (1e3,100) (1e4,80) (1e5,20) (1e6,0)};
        \node[above] at (axis cs:5e3,90) {$-6$};
        \node[above] at (axis cs:5e4,50) {$-12$};
        \node[above] at (axis cs:5e5,10) {$-6$};
    \end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]